# How can I convert those string to bool?

Tags: c#, json

I'm using a GET JSON request to know the status of a transaction (checked every 5 seconds):

```
string webAddr = "https://shapeshift.io/txStat/" + textBox1.Text;

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionStatus>(responseText);
        }

        if (TransactionStatus.status = "no_deposits")
        {
            label7.Text = "Pending..";
        }
        else if (TransactionStatus.status = "received")
        {
            label7.Text = "Received..";
        }
        else if (TransactionStatus.status = "complete")
        {
            label7.Text = "Completed !";
        }
        else
        {
            label7.Text = "...";
        }
```

My problem is that I can't check this string value because it need to be "bool". How can I change this to bool ? Or there is any other way to do that check I'm trying to do ? Thanks !

Comment: You're assigning values in your `if` statement by using a single equals sign.  Change `TransactionStatus.status = ...` to `TransactionStatus.status == ...`

Comment: Lol i'm so dump, thanks !

Comment: I'd recommend using `switch(TransactionStatus.status)` instead of this `if .. else if` nightmare.

Comment: I will try to use switch right now

Comment: Btw.: Shouldn't you be checking `apiResponse.status`? To me `TransactionStatus.status` looks like a static property of your class/type `TransactionStatus`, not the deserialzed value you intend to check.

Answer (score 2):

== not =.

```
TransactionStatus.status = "no_deposits"
```

should be

```
TransactionStatus.status == "no_deposits"
```

otherwise it thinks you're assigning a value to the status, not comparing it.

Comment: It's funny how many times I've solved problem just after I've posted it.